# Обновление формы после редактирования

Tags: php, html, form, submit, обновление

Есть форма в которой происходит редактировании информации , после нажатия кнопки "Сохранить" происходит сохранение отредактированной информации, но чтобы увидеть эту отредактированную информацию в форме,страницу надо ещё раз обновить,как сделать автоматическое обновление формы ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>редактирование клиента</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include_once("db1.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$rezult=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM klienti WHERE id='$id' ");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rezult);
if (isset($_POST['save']))
{
    $klient = strip_tags(trim($_POST['klient']))  ;
    $op_firma=strip_tags(trim($_POST['op_forma']))  ;
    $naimen=strip_tags(trim($_POST['naimen']))  ;
    $otrasl=strip_tags(trim($_POST['otrasl']))  ;
    $telefon=strip_tags(trim($_POST['telefon']))  ;
    $email=strip_tags(trim($_POST['email']))  ;
    $kont_lico=strip_tags(trim($_POST['kont_lico']))  ;
    $dolznost=strip_tags(trim($_POST['dolznost']))  ;
     mysql_query("
    UPDATE klienti SET klient='$klient', op_forma='$op_firma', naimen='$naimen',otrasl='$otrasl',telefon='$telefon',email='$email',kont_lico='$kont_lico',dolznost='$dolznost' WHERE id='$id' 
           ");
     mysql_close();
}

?>

<form method="post" action="edit.php?id=<?php  echo $id; ?>" id="form">
    клиент<br/>
<input type="text" name="klient" value="<?php  echo $row['klient'] ;  ?>" /><br/>
    ОП_форма <br/>
<input  type="text"  name="op_forma" value="<?php  echo $row['op_forma'] ; ?>" />  <br/> <!-- cols="10" rows="10" -->
    Наимен <br/>
<input type="text" name="naimen" value="<?php  echo $row['naimen'] ;  ?>" /><br/><br/>
отрасль <br/>
<input type="text" name="otrasl" value="<?php  echo $row['otrasl'] ;  ?>" /><br/><br/>
telefon <br/>
<input type="text" name="telefon" value="<?php  echo $row['telefon'] ;  ?>"  /><br/><br/>
email <br/>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php  echo $row['email'] ;  ?>" /><br/><br/>
ОП фирмы <br/>
<input type="text" name="kont_lico"  value="<?php  echo $row['kont_lico'] ;  ?>"/><br/><br/>
ОП фирмы <br/>
<input type="text" name="dolznost" value="<?php  echo $row['dolznost'] ;  ?>" /><br/><br/>
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo date ('Y-m-d');?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="time" value="<?php echo date ('H:i:s');?>" />
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Сохранить"  />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно же надо чтобы извлечение данных из базы следовало после обновления базы

```
...
$id = $_GET['id'];
// Перенести за обновление
// $rezult=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM klienti WHERE id='$id' ");
// $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rezult);
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $klient = strip_tags(trim($_POST['klient']))  ;
    $op_firma=strip_tags(trim($_POST['op_forma']))  ;
    $naimen=strip_tags(trim($_POST['naimen']))  ;
    $otrasl=strip_tags(trim($_POST['otrasl']))  ;
    $telefon=strip_tags(trim($_POST['telefon']))  ;
    $email=strip_tags(trim($_POST['email']))  ;
    $kont_lico=strip_tags(trim($_POST['kont_lico']))  ;
    $dolznost=strip_tags(trim($_POST['dolznost']))  ;
    mysql_query("UPDATE klienti SET klient='$klient', op_forma='$op_firma', naimen='$naimen',otrasl='$otrasl',telefon='$telefon',email='$email',kont_lico='$kont_lico',dolznost='$dolznost' WHERE id='$id'");
}
// Теперь извлекаются самые свежие данные, насколько это возможно
$rezult=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM klienti WHERE id='$id' ");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rezult);
mysql_close();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

После успешного редактирования сделайте редирект на эту же страницу и все.

```
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```